# Static input and Dynamic input result not the same

Tags: c, openssl

From this [code source](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)
The key and iv are hardcoded so I tried changing it so that it can be gotten dynamically like so:

```
// gets user's input value
    int length = 100; //initial size
    char * keyVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    char * ivVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    int count = 0; //to keep track of how many chars have been used
    char c; // to store the current char

    printf("\n  Enter your key value : ");
    gets(keyVal);

    printf("\n  Enter your iv value : ");
    gets(ivVal);


    free(ivVal);
    free(keyVal);

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ //keep reading until a newline
    if(count >= length)
        keyVal = realloc(keyVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        ivVal = realloc(ivVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
    keyVal[count++] = c;
    ivVal[count++] = c;
    }


    /* A 128 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = keyVal;

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = ivVal;
```

Unfortunately the decripted output generated using static and dynamic input are different(screenshot below).
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Please how can I dynamically get iv and key value?

*I should point out that I used exactly the same key, iv and plaintext when testing this.*

Full code is:

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>
// run: gcc filename.c -o outputname -lcrypto

void handleErrors(void);
int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext);
int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext);

int main (void)
{
    /*
     * Set up the key and iv. Do I need to say to not hard code these in a
     * real application? :-)
     */




     // gets user's input value
    int length = 100; //initial size
    char * keyVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    char * ivVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    int count = 0; //to keep track of how many chars have been used
    char c; // to store the current char

    printf("\n  Enter your key value : ");
    gets(keyVal);

    printf("\n  Enter your iv value : ");
    gets(ivVal);


    free(ivVal);
    free(keyVal);

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ //keep reading until a newline
    if(count >= length)
        keyVal = realloc(keyVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        ivVal = realloc(ivVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
    keyVal[count++] = c;
    ivVal[count++] = c;
    }


    /* A 128 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = keyVal;

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = ivVal;

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext =
        (unsigned char *)"This is the top secret message in parallel computing! Please keep it in a safe place.";

    /*
     * Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
     * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, depending on the
     * algorithm and mode.
     */
    unsigned char ciphertext[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = encrypt (plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), key, iv,
                              ciphertext);

    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
                                decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    /* Show the decrypted text */
    printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);


    return 0;
}


void handleErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}


int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. No need to multiply with that.

Answer (score 1):

Freeing buffers that will be used later is bad. Delete these lines:

```
    free(ivVal);
    free(keyVal);
```

or move the lines at the end of its function (just before the `return` line).

Also the part

```
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ //keep reading until a newline
    if(count >= length)
        keyVal = realloc(keyVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        ivVal = realloc(ivVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
    keyVal[count++] = c;
    ivVal[count++] = c;
    }
```

is bad because

- Indentation is not consistent.
- The line `ivVal = realloc(ivVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char));` is executed regardless of whether `count >= length`
- Different length will be used for `keyVal` and `ivVal` because `length` is updated on the allocations.
- Doing `count++` twice also looks weird.

I guess it should be:

```
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ //keep reading until a newline
        if(count >= length){
            length += 10;
            keyVal = realloc(keyVal, length * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
            ivVal = realloc(ivVal, length * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        }
        keyVal[count] = c;
        ivVal[count] = c;
        count++;
    }
```

Adding checks whether `malloc()`s and `realloc()`s are successful will improve the code more.